# Generate type from schema

Tags: typescript

I am trying to generate a type from a schema (array of object).

```
const config = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    value: 'xx',
  },
] as const;
```

Is it possible to dynamically generate an interface like below?

```
interface Config {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
```

I tried this

```
type Config<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = {
  [k in T[number]['name']]: any; // how to get the correct type but not any
};

type Res = Config<typeof config>;
```

got

```
type Res = {
    a: any;
    b: any;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "schema"? Your post doesn't contain any schema definitions that I'm aware of.

Comment: A simple schema is an array. Each object contains two keys `name` and `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to get the corresponding type of the `value` property. Only mark `config.name` `as const` otherwise `config.value` will be mapped to the literal as well.

```
const config = [
  {
    name: "a" as const,
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "b" as const,
    value: "xx"
  }
];

type Config<T extends readonly {name: string; value: any}[]> = {
  [K in T[number]["name"]]: Extract<T[number], {name: K}>["value"];
};

type Res = Config<typeof config>;
//   ^? type Res = { a: number; b: string; }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeGBtAsAKBhgG99DCwBDAWwFMAuGAIgsZgojnGgBpSyA3CgBsArvRgBGPgF9eBYn3LVxjAEat2nSFDlkYg0SoAeRxjPwBdANz58UAJ4AHGjADC4ZCgA8AFRg0jKBowABMOACcaChDwIXtiSloGaHCkMBQrfWExBgowe2ksCwA+DAV5LABpGDSYHywwESpVGnCLLEZEmkYLCwYAUUDwimAoXwamlrbuBOUGSulijoMxHps8aXW7JxcAJRoOTHdEVC8HZxAELU9i9YB6O7IAPQB+fCA)

Comment: It works, but too many `as const`.